# docker command exposes ports correctly but docker-compose doesn't

Tags: docker, networking

I am attempting to expose a vue.js server running inside my docker container in a docker-compose setup. However, although I can build the individual container to do this correctly, I can't get it to work using docker-compose.

When I run the command - `docker run -p 8888:8080 client` (after building the client image), I'm able to access the default vue page at localhost:8888.

However, when I run `docker-compose up` I'm not able to do it.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` -

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  client:
    restart: always
    container_name: client
    ports:
      - "8888:8080"
    environment:
      - VUE_CLI_BABEL_TARGET_NODE=true 
      - VUE_CLI_BABEL_TRANSPILE_MODULES=true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./client/:/client/"
```

Here is my `Dockerfile` -

```
FROM node:10-alpine

ARG PORT=8080
ENV PORT=$PORT

WORKDIR /client

RUN apk update && apk add --update bash git openssl yarn wget curl && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY client /client

RUN yarn install && yarn serve
```

It should be noted that I am using Docker for Mac.

EDIT:
This is the output of `docker container ps --no-trunc`.

```
CONTAINER ID                                                       IMAGE                                                                     COMMAND                                     CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
049db2af69db9979c5d3feea92d7b039f6c06502f24f76ce4da75f104ff5cf60   sha256:597bb7c8dd1b3c8510b565f211873c40935a6ac9d434f9379651fab94c9f1a7d   "/bin/sh -c 'yarn install && yarn serve'"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            agitated_stallman
d86d0c4dcc3168705f0f949876823cf4c0188161a53754788d88c20e3e42d250   sha256:b332d7c0a2af04303eac7f37f566f0451bbb222b051705d9c9e6ca8e2e97e291   "/bin/sh -c 'yarn install && yarn serve'"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                              mystifying_payne
```

First is image, second docker-compose up. They're different.

Comment: Are there any differences in your `docker container ps --no-trunc` output between the two methods? If they are the same, then I'd suggest looking inside the container for the issue. I'd also try the docker-compose method without the build process to ensure you are getting the same image.

Comment: @Ryan docker-compose without the build causes the same problem.

Comment: 049db2af69db9979c5d3feea92d7b039f6c06502f24f76ce4da75f104ff5cf60   sha256:597bb7c8dd1b3c8510b565f211873c40935a6ac9d434f9379651fab94c9f1a7d   "/bin/sh -c 'yarn install && yarn serve'"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes                            agitated_stallman
d86d0c4dcc3168705f0f949876823cf4c0188161a53754788d88c20e3e42d250   sha256:b332d7c0a2af04303eac7f37f566f0451bbb222b051705d9c9e6ca8e2e97e291   "/bin/sh -c 'yarn install && yarn serve'"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                              mystifying_payne

First is image, second docker-compose up. They're different.

Comment: Make sure your containers are stopping properly. You can only bind a port on one container at a time. I'm not sure your `ARG` line makes much sense, unless you have a particular case for it. Those are build-time variables, so you are mixing build-time (ARG) and runtime (ENV) together. Try using `docker run ... client:latest` and `image: client:latest` and confirming you can get docker and docker-compose to run an identical image with same digest.